# Performance: DELETE vs FORALL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What has better performance?

DELETE like this:

```
    DELETE FROM users WHERE attr IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(attrs));
```

or FORALL like this:

```
    FORALL i IN 1..attrs.COUNT DELETE FROM users WHERE attr = attrs(i);
```

Comment: Hands down, Single `DELETE` is faster and DB friendly ! `FORALL DELETE` is just better than `DELETE` inside a `FOR LOOP`, by saving context switching between PL/SQL Engine and SQL Engine, as `FORALL` uses `BULK BINDING`

Comment: what you mean by "Single DELETE" ? DELETE FROM users WHERE attr IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(attrs)) is a single delete ?

Comment: Yes, David. Single DML statement, to delete all your records.

Comment: @OracleUser You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

***Single `DELETE`*** is faster and more appropriate in this simple case. The OP might have ignored it was possible to delete several records at once with a simple `DELETE`.

`FORALL DELETE` is just better than `DELETE` inside a `FOR LOOP`, it avoid switching context between PL/SQL and SQL. Indeed, **`FORALL` uses `BULK BINDING`**